# Firebase - Passwordless sign-in quota exceeded just after 5 requests?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am a bit shocked at what I observed. I am 100% sure that I have generated only 5 links for testing my web application however in the documentation it says 20,000 sign-in links generated per day:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits
[image]
Am I missing something here? Because testing app for less than 5 links a day would be extremely hard. Can I turn on some debugging options? Like we used to have on otp verifications where we could add dummy otps and test them as per the requirement?

Edit: I also see this:

[image]

Does this mean we can only request 5 emails a day for passwordless sign in? Is there a way to create a mocked email address for development and testing purposes?

Comment: Found the cause? Or a solution for this?

Comment: Nothing as of now

Comment: You have to add a credit card and upgrade to Blaze plan. Google will charge you only if you go above the free tier.